# Listview in Listview

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listview.setadapter raising nullpointer exception.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244797/listview-setadapter-raising-nullpointer-exception)

Hi, How to create a listview in a listview. I have a tabbar application. The second tab is a list view, when a cell in the listview is clicked, it should showthe next list view. How to do this?

I have tried some thing here 
[Listview.setadapter raising nullpointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244797/listview-setadapter-raising-nullpointer-exception)

The error is as below. is it possible to do it in the way as in the previous question. are there any easier methods.

Comment: Instead of asking a new question for the same problem, you should clarify your existing question. You don't need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

When I understand the question correctly, you are looking for that: [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: No thats not. I want to click a cell item and a new list view appears to the right of the parent listview. in a new window.

Comment: Than you should simply start a new activity or switch the tab to your new listview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244797/listview-setadapter-raising-nullpointer-exception.  I have created a new activity.

Comment: The code is as in the above question.